# Permanently set position of relatively-placed items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a row of evenly-spaced navigation items, which looks like this:

[image]

The currently selected menu item is bold-italic. The designer wants the others to turn bold-italic on hover. When this happens, it makes the text of that item wider, which nudges all the other items over because they are displayed inline with a fixed margin. I have to get rid of the nudging.

What's the right way to fix this behavior? I have a couple ideas using javascript:

- Onload, wrap the text up in divs and set the width of each div to the width of the text.
- Onload, take the positions of each of the menu items relative to the div, then set their positions to absolute with the resulting coordinates (this would be okay because they are always in the same absolute position within the nav div).

These both seem a little hackish, and it's a pretty simple problem so I thought there must be an easier way.

I'm using jQuery if it makes a difference.

The following is a fairly minimal HTML page that will reproduce the issue:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: black;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    a {
        margin: 0px 20px;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="projectslink" href="#projects">Projects</a>
    <a id="innovationslink" href="#innovations">Innovations</a>
    <a id="newslink" href="#news">News</a>
    <a id="aboutlink" href="#about">About</a>
    <a id="contactlink" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a id="breathlink" href="#">Breath*</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/pRhKF/10/

Obviously you would have to adapt that to make it fit in to your own code. It makes all the `a`s have the width they will have when the text is made bold by momentarily bolding them and then un-bolding them. Unfortunately I also had to use the `hover` event binder to achieve the mouse over effect, but maybe you can find a way around doing that...

Comment: @John: this does mean the `:hover` state won't work for users with JavaScript disabled (although those are rare, these days).

Comment: Oh sorry I'm not used to jsfiddle, my solution fixes that but I accidentally reposted Max's. My solution uses css hover: http://jsfiddle.net/jmcdon10/UdJZ5/

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an elegant solution to this time-old CSS problem... I can think of two "hackish" CSS solutions to choose from:

- Give the items `display: block-inline` and a fixed width (in `em`, of course, to prevent font scaling / zoom problems). Width will differ from item to item if the padding should look consistent.
- Hide the text and replace replace it with images.

In my opinion, *your* first solution (setting fixed width `onload`) isn't that bad. It "feels right" not to mess with `position` and is, at the very least, much less hackish than the alternatives.

To clarify, this is how I would implement your first solution:

**HTML**: no change

**CSS**: no change

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(function() {    
    $('a').each(function() {
        var menuItem = $(this);
        menuItem.css({
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'width':   menuItem.outerWidth(true),
            'margin':  0,
            'text-align': 'center'
        }); 
    });
});
```

As you can see:

- There is no need to wrap the menu items in a div (just set `display: block-inline` from JS);
- Each separate item can be kept centered by setting the width to the *computed* `outerWidth()` (which includes margin, padding and border width), clearing the `margin` and setting `text-align` to `center`.

Live example [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/fbSCX/).

Comment: I'm not totally sure since you didn't include code but I don't think solution 1 will solve this problem. To be clear, the space between the items needs to be fixed, whereas I think no matter what with a fixed item width it will vary.

Comment: @John: to be clear, I meant your own solution number 1. I'll clarify in my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry no I got that, I meant the first one you listed. And of course your second idea *would* work for my case (although I'd prefer the javascript route in this case). You clarified the alternatives really well, so I thanks for that!

Comment: @John: ah, OK. No, my first point is *very* hackish. It involves (manually) esstimating the width for each item and it will only work if the font rendering is consistent across browsers. Lot of unknowns, there...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like to give my nav some list markup, then give the anchor elements block display with a width:

http://jsfiddle.net/9AEnv/

I float the li, but you can also give them a display: inline-block if you want to avoid floats.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite solve my problem because the space between items needs to be fixed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you're saying is the space between the items needs to be the same, not fixed. Is that correct? The space between items is fixed in my solution, but it's not the same for each because the length of text for each varies.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Max Spencer's solution above using javascript was what I was looking for (although it would have been awesome to do it in just css).

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, this is the solution I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/jmcdon10/UdJZ5/

Mostly based on @Max's answer (which itself was a reworking of my first proposed solution), but using css hover instead of jQuery's hover event binder.